# CMS tree structure in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages

We are looking for a method to build up the cms pages in Magento 2 with a tree structure so that you can set hierarchy. For Magento 1 you have several modules, but we didn't find anything for Magento 2 yet.

Does anyone have experience with a module for this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

**This is only on Enterprise Edition**

It appears to be in Magento 2 already, log in to the admin and navigate to **CMS > Hierarchy**

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice, which version of magento are you using? Is this EE? I am pretty sure we do not have this in CE 2.1.3 ;( Or I have been really ignorant

Comment: It is a Magento EE feature! Not for CE.

Comment: Damn it, my bad. I'll leave the answer here in case it helps someone on EE.

Comment: Yes to bad we are using CE, why is this not added to the community version?

Comment: @Coen - It's probably so more people purchase EE, if both editions were the same why would anyone pay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I think you are totally right with that, but think with some of the things with CE that it should just be in there, this is pretty basic stuff. I will now probably fix this by implementing Wordpress and then building it up in there. Next to that I also don't think that someone would or would not purchase it because of this reason.

Comment: Very true, this one reason alone isn't really enough but if you include the other reasons to purchase it (better caching etc.) then it'll be enough to convince some people.

Comment: Such BS to have this in EE only.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Magento Open Source (Magento Community Edition) — then it is not possible out of the box. You might choose [CMS Pages Navigation Magento 2](https://www.magesolution.com/cms-pages-navigation-for-magento-2.html) module. This module is designed for admins who are not familiar with coding when you need a can-be-assigned list page. Just find the page(s) you want to add menu and Save!